# Python Twisted LineReceiver class variables?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using the LineReceiver class in the python Twisted library. I see from the LineReceiver source code that the mdethods setLineMode and setRawMode set the class variable line_mode to 1 or 0. Also there is another class variable called _buffer which I assume stores data sent over the connection.

But why are line_mode and _buffer class variables? Doesn't this mean that if my factory creates multiple instances of LineReceiver (or protocols that inherit from LineReceiver) that if I set line_mode=1 then ALL LineReceiver protocol instances then go into line mode? And doesn't this also mean that there is only one _buffer for ALL instances of LineReceiver? I don't understand. Can someone please explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. Yes the LineReceiver class does indeed have class variables _buffer and line_mode. However, what it actually uses inside the LineReceiver methods are instance variables with the same name. When python creates an instance of any class that has class variables, it also creates instance variables of the same name, and these instance variables have whatever value the class variable had when the instance was created.

So for example, the instance can check self.line_mode which is the value for the instance variable line_mode. If this is the first time the instance variable was accessed, it should have the same value as the corresponding class variable. But if you change it, it gets a new value different from that of the class variable. I guess this is just some of the hidden stuff that goes on under the hood in python.

You can always still get the value of the class variable line_mode by accessing LineReceiver.line_mode.

Just thought I'd write this in case anyone else (like me) is new to python and twisted and got confused.

Comment: Until you try to change (assign) `self.line_mode`; it refers to the same object for all class instances i.e., Python does not create separate instance variables for class attributes, it is just how the attribute lookup works in general. You can demonstrate it by using a mutable object such as list as a class attribute: if you call `self.the_list.append(1)`; all other instances will see the changed value (because it is the same object).